# app does not show on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and 7.0

Tags: android, permissions, app-store

I just released an app but it can not be downloaded through the Play Store app on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and Tab 2 7.0. But when side load it works fine. I suspect the permissions are causing the problem. Here is the list of permissions, could you tell which one is causing the problem? I suspect it is the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE because the tabs do not have phone capability. Is that the problem? THanks

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<!-- Mobclix Required Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- Mobclix Optional Permissions -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:required="false" />
```

Edit:
It perhaps is not because of that permission, because I saw the older version of Galaxy tabs , Motorola Xoom and Asus Transformer are all supported.
Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Play filtering is usually a result of permissions that imply hardware features.

Take a look at the documentation for permissions related to [`<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) and add the `android:required="false"` attribute setting to any features which are not required.

There's a good chance it could be the camera auto-focus feature which is causing the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Squonk, I think you are right. I wrote a test app and the tablets that are not supported do not have the auto focus feature. It is weird that  older Galaxy tabs support it but tab 2 does not. Will upload a new build and see if that is really the problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is the problem. Auto Focus is not supported on about 300 devices :(. The camera has been causing us problems all along. Each manufacture has its own implementations.

Comment: @Ray : Glad that fixed it although you obviously need to work around that issue. Setting `android:required="false"` for the feature will help when it comes to the Google Play filtering but also (obviously) you'll need to check `hasSystemFeature(...)` at runtime to enable/disable aspects of your app. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Are these elements present in your Android manifest? If not, does adding these help?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: I do not have those settings. However I do not think that is the problem. Because the app is supported by Galaxy Tab 10.1 but not Galaxy Tab 2 10.1. They have the same screen density and resolution.